# Sencha losing scope on function calling

Tags: function, extjs, scope, bind

I am trying to call a generic function but when that function is executed I am in a different scope (window). This code will picture the case:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    context: null,

    function1 : function(){
        this.function2(this.function3);
    },

    function2 : function(func){
        func();
    },

    function3 : function(){
        if(context == this){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Same context!');
        }
        else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Different context!');
        }
    },

    launch : function() {
        context = this;
        this.function1();
    }
});
```

I am trying to use bind but it is not working.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am so sorry guys, I said Javascript instead of Sencha. I thought the issue would be the same in Javascript and I could get more help. I apologise. I created a code in fiddle to replicate the issue. Thanks to all the comments and help, they are really appreciated!

Comment: Provide more code. The code you provided isn't even syntactically correct and will give a syntax error.

Comment: Functions can't lose their scope. What you mean is that the context on which they are called is unexpected.

Comment: @FelixKling, PitaJ: I guess those functions are part of an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to bind your context (`this`).

```
function1 : function(arg){
    this.function2(this.function3.bind(this), arg) // using bind
},

function2 : function(func, arg){
    func(arg);    // <-- Issue
},

function3 : function(arg){
    // this = window... I lost the scope??
},
```

Comment: Since `function2` is called as a normal function `this` will also refer to `window` there as well.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Editing my answer now.

Comment: @FelixKling It seems like this is being called in an object with the structure `var objName = { func1: function () {}, func2: function () {}, func2: function () {} }` but if that was the case the context should be the same in `func3`. I guess we need more info.

Comment: @FelixKling: It probably is `this.function2(…)` anyway

Comment: Sorry guys, I corrected the code above. The issue is happening in Sencha but I thought it would be the same in Javascript and I ended up messing things up.

Comment: I will create a new question. This is quite a mess. Sorry for the inconvenience.